# How to set array first element dynamically with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array as follows,

```
<?php
    $arr = array('op'=>'pqr', 'ab'=>'xyz', 'mn'=>'abcd');

?>
```

How to set `xyz` value as first element with minimum loop,if the value exist.

Expected Result

```
<?php
    $arr = array('ab'=>'xyz', 'op'=>'pqr','mn'=>'abcd');
?>
```

Comment: @notme, alfasin is correct, but I might suggest that if you require order in this array, that you consider storing your data in a different manner.  You can have an array of arrays, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ab = $array['ab'];
unset($array['ab']);
$array = array('ab' => $ab) + $array;
```

If the key itself is unknown, find it first:

```
$key = array_search('xyz', $array);
$tmp = $array[$key];
unset($array[$key]);
$array = array($key => $tmp) + $array;
```

Or go with a sort:

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a == 'xyz') return -1;
    if ($b == 'xyz') return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    $arr = array('op'=>'pqr', 'ab'=>'xyz', 'mn'=>'abcd');
    ksort($arr);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
```

Comment: This won't give the result that OP is trying to get, it'll sort the array by key.